# What do these phrases mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Regional organizations are becoming increasingly active, perhaps **in recognition that an under-resourced** UN system needs assistance to implement its security mandate at the regional and national levels.
>   The EU and the less well known but influential OSCE (Organization for Security and Cooperation in Europe) is the most extensive European security organization **in that it includes** Russia as the successor to the Soviet Union.
>   **With the** North Atlantic Treaty Organization (NATO) incorporating the USA, the OSCE’s mission is evolving from being a facilitator of security dialogue and a promoter of democratization to engagement in the business of peacekeeping.
>   According to Nina Graeger and Alexandra Novosseloff, this organization ‘is the most important norm-building organization in Europe’, although this effectiveness is limited by renewed strategic rivalry between the USA and Russia.

<sup>ORIGINAL TEXT SHOULD NOT BE CHANGED (I'm only translating not editing). Text came from [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=uRyJCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=Regional%20organizations%20are%20becoming%20increasingly%20active,%20perhaps%20in%20recognition%20that%20an%20under-%20resourced%20UN%20system%20needs%20assistance%20to%20implement%20its%20security%20mandate%20at%20the%20regional%20and%20national%20levels.The%20EU%20and%20the%20less%20well%20known%20but%20influential%20OSCE%20%28Organization%20for%20Security%20and%20Cooperation%20in%20Europe%29%20is%20the%20most%20extensive%20European%20security%20organization%20in%20that%20it%20includes%20Russia%20as%20the%20successor%20to%20the%20Soviet%20Union.With%20the%20North%20Atlantic%20Treaty%20Organization%20%28NATO%29%20incorporating%20the%20USA,%20the%20OSCE%E2%80%99s%20mission%20is%20evolving%20from%20being%20a%20facilitator%20of%20security%20dialogue%20and%20a%20promoter%20of%20democratization%20to%20engagement%20in%20the%20business%20of%20peacekeeping.According%20to%20Nina%20Graeger%20and%20Alexandra%20Novosseloff,%20this%20organization%20%E2%80%98is%20the%20most%20important%20norm-building%20organization%20in%20Europe%E2%80%99,%20although%20this%20effectiveness%20is%20limited%20by%20renewed%20strategic%20rivalry%20between%20the%20USA%20and%20Russia.&source=bl&ots=YyiB_GYG2D&sig=E61Pr8hCtvO1WDAi7dEZ7LtCgRU&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif2r3Giu3LAhXG3CwKHd1iC7MQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Regional%20organizations%20are%20becoming%20increasingly%20active%2C%20perhaps%20in%20recognition%20that%20an%20under-%20resourced%20UN%20system%20needs%20assistance%20to%20implement%20its%20security%20mandate%20at%20the%20regional%20and%20national%20levels.The%20EU%20and%20the%20less%20well%20known%20but%20influential%20OSCE%20%28Organization%20for%20Security%20and%20Cooperation%20in%20Europe%29%20is%20the%20most%20extensive%20European%20security%20organization%20in%20that%20it%20includes%20Russia%20as%20the%20successor%20to%20the%20Soviet%20Union.With%20the%20North%20Atlantic%20Treaty%20Organization%20%28NATO%29%20incorporating%20the%20USA%2C%20the%20OSCE%E2%80%99s%20mission%20is%20evolving%20from%20being%20a%20facilitator%20of%20security%20dialogue%20and%20a%20promoter%20of%20democratization%20to%20engagement%20in%20the%20business%20of%20peacekeeping.According%20to%20Nina%20Graeger%20and%20Alexandra%20Novosseloff%2C%20this%20organization%20%E2%80%98is%20the%20most%20important%20norm-building%20organization%20in%20Europe%E2%80%99%2C%20although%20this%20effectiveness%20is%20limited%20by%20renewed%20strategic%20rivalry%20between%20the%20USA%20and%20Russia.&f=false)</sup>

I'm completly confused about this paragraph:

1. What does "in recognition" mean here? I think it means "after recognizing the importance of issue" (?)
2. What does author mean in calling UN as an "under-resourced" system? i can't understand (maybe it means dependent system to nations(?)
3. What is reference of "that" and "it" in here? that=EU  and it=osce(?)

Comment: "in recognition": having recognised, noticed, acknowledge. 
"in that it includes": i.e. it is the only European security organisation that assumes Russia as the successor to the Soviet Union.

Comment: Three good questions that should be in three separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative phrasing (in this context):

1. "In recognition" = "because they recognize"
2. "Under-resourced" = "has less resources than it requires to meet its objectives"

"It" refers to the OSCE. "In that" is a phrase that means "due to the fact that", or simply "because", in this context. The EU is not referred to directly in the sentence (although, indirectly, you can deduce that unlike the OSCE it *does not* include Russia).